# Storing High Scores JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

```
<html>

    <body> <pre>    
    <script language ='JavaScript'>

document.write(" \n Welcome to the type what you see game the objective of the game is to simply answer what you see on screen by typing into the prompt box, you will press on the answer button next \n to the pictures and type and answer. Once you have moved down the page and had a go at all 5 questions, your result will be displayed once you press the result button. A correct \n answer will be worth 1 pointn an incorrect answer will be worth 0 points, best of luck!")

var r = 0;

function checkAnswer() {

    a = prompt('What animal is in the image?');
    if (a == 'dog') {
        alert('Well Done. Correct answer');
        r++;
    } else {
        alert('Sorry, incorrect, it is a dog');
    }

}

function checkAnswer2() {
    b = prompt('What animal is in the image?');
    if (b == 'hamster') {
        alert('Well Done. Correct answer');
        r++;
    } else {
        alert('Sorry, incorrect, it is a hamster');
    }
}

function checkAnswer3() {
    c = prompt('What animal is in the image?');
    if (c == 'hedgehog') {
        alert('Well Done. Correct answer');
        r++;
    } else {
        alert('Sorry, incorrect, it is a hedgehog');

    }

}

function checkAnswer4() {
    d = prompt('What animal is in the image?');
    if (d == 'turtle') {
        alert('Well Done. Correct answer');
        r++;
    } else {
        alert('Sorry, incorrect, it is a turtle');
    }
}

function checkAnswer5() {
    e = prompt('What animal is in the image?');
    if (e == 'hare') {
        alert('Well Done. Correct answer');
        r++;
    } else {
        alert('Sorry, incorrect, it is a hare');
    }
}

function showResult() {
    alert('the number of questions you answered correct was ' + r + ' 
    questions');

}

    </script>

    </pre>

        <p>Question 1. What is this an image of?</p>
        <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/532abed3e4b025f227941d11/t/532ce5e3e4b0f59c2979d8c2/1395451365611/" class="image1">
        <button onclick="checkAnswer()">Answer</button>
        <p>Question 2. What is this an image of?</p>
        <img src="http://www.hamsters.co.uk/hamsters_images/syrian-hamster_000008437184.jpg" class="image2">
        <button onclick="checkAnswer2()">Answer</button>
        <p>Question 3. What is this an image of?</p>
        <img src="http://www.hellohedgehog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Hedgehog-7.jpg" class="image3">
        <button onclick="checkAnswer3()">Answer</button>
        <p>Question 4. What is this an image of?</p>
        <img src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/turtle-shell-1.jpg" class="image4">
        <button onclick="checkAnswer4()">Answer</button>
        <p>Question 5. What is this an image of?</p>
        <img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Education/Pix/pictures/2011/5/19/1305816821363/The-Irish-hare-is-under-t-007.jpg" class="image5">
        <button onclick="checkAnswer5()">Answer</button>
        <button onclick="showResult()">Result</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

As I am new to javascript, what would be the easiest way too store a high score, I have a score displaying when you click result, but would be nice to store the users scores?

Comment: You need some sort of server side storage. a text file or database.

Comment: If you want to store it locally, you could use a cookie or HTML5 client store. If you want to store it on your server, then you need to write a server side application that will store it on your server, in a database or some other storage method.

Answer (score 1):

### Cookies

The easiest way to do this, would likely be to use a cookie.

For your example, you might be able to do something like this:

```
document.cookie = "highscore=" + r;
```

You can read more about document.cookie at:
[the mozilla mdn page for document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage to store something

```
if( typeof(Storage) !== undefined) {
  if(localStorage.high) {
    if(localStorage.high < r) {
      localStorage.high = r;
    }
  } else {
    localStorage.high = 0;
  }
}
//this script changes the localStorage
if(r > localStorage.high) {
  localStorage.high = r;
}
```

You can also clear the localStorage

```
localStorage.clear()
```